# C++ init multiple class object inside for loop gives the same memory address?

Tags: c++, memory, initialization

My code snippet is as follows, however when I have 2 self defined classes and I define them, and print their memory address:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    Engine b;
    Strategy d;
    std::cout<<"be:"<<&b<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"elm:"<<&d<<std::endl;
}
```

it outputs:

> be:0x7ffd92aee2c0
>
> elm:0x7ffd92aede70
>
> be:0x7ffd92aee2c0
>
> elm:0x7ffd92aede70

i was expecting 2 different sets of memory addresses, but they are the same. Can someone tell me how to init into different address?

Comment: Why do you think they should have different memory addresses?

Comment: They are both local to the loop body, what difference does it make? [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Every time through the loop, the objects get constructed and then destructed. The compiler uses the same memory every time because why not?

Comment: i thought all the variables are destroyed and recreated for each iteration of the loop

Comment: You thought right.  Once they are destroyed, there is no reason for the memory they once used not to be used again.

Comment: If you really want an answer about why they have the same address, this is not a C++ question. You can easily see why if you have some knowledge of assembly.

Comment: i get it guys, thank yall for the answers. I felt stupid because obviously it's reusing the old memory addess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way is

```
Engine b[2];
Strategy d[2];
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    std::cout<<"be:"<<&b[i]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"elm:"<<&d[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

but the real question is why you care that the addresses are the same. Most likely its not something you need to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

> i was expecting 2 different sets of memory address

There is no reason to expect that. By the time the next iteration begins, the lifetime of the automatic object in the previous iteration has ended and so the object in the next iteration can reuse the same storage i.e. it can have the same memory address.

> Can someone tell me how to init into different address?

You cannot specify the memory location where an object of automatic storage duration is allocated. But, if you create two objects whose lifetime overlaps, then they must necessarily be stored in separate addresses. john has shown how to do that using an array in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48624898/2079303).

Answer (score 2):

Both of the variables that you have outputted should only have 1 unique memory address, be, which is equal to

> 0x7ffd92aee2c0

was outputted twice, with no change to it whatsoever.

Then

> elm:0x7ffd92aede70

was the same scenario, you outputted it twice with no change, what difference did you expect?

The code is working perfectly fine!

Comment: This misses the point - it's not a single address to a single variable that's output twice, but 2 addresses to 2 differently scoped variables that just happen to be the same

Answer (score 1):

Objects created within block scope are created each time the block is entered and destroyed each time the block is left. In case of a loop, your objects `b` and `d` will be created and destroyed with each begin and end of an iteration, respectively. So you will get "new" objects with each iteration, but the compiler is free to use any address (even the ones used for the object of the prior iteration), so it may happen that you see the same addresses again and again. But it might also happen that you get different ones. Anyway, it makes no sense to rely on memory addresses of object which's life time has ended / will end, so the more interesting question is: "why do you care about memory addresses of `e` and `d` at all?".

To bring some light into that what happens try the following code. It shows how objects are created and destroyed in the course of your program:

```
class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass (int x=0) : x (x) { cout << "Constructing " << x << endl; };
    TestClass (const TestClass& t) : x (t.x) { cout << "CopyConstructing " << x << endl; };
    TestClass (const TestClass&& t) : x (t.x) { cout << "Moving " << x << endl; };
    ~TestClass () { cout << "Destructing " << x << endl; };

    int x;
};

int  main() {

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        TestClass b(i);
        std::cout<<"elm:"<<&b<<std::endl;
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
Constructing 0
elm:0x7fff5fbff780
Destructing 0
Constructing 1
elm:0x7fff5fbff780
Destructing 1
```